# Angular 7 how to use new @aiStore

Tags: angular, angular7

I read that Angular 7 comes with a new feature call @aiStore.
I didn't found how I can install the new module and how can I use it.

can anyone point me for more details about how to download this new feature?
is there any Angular DOC for this?

Comment: You do know that https://moduscreate.com/blog/top-4-changes-coming-in-angular-7-0/ this article was published the 1 of april right? It's a joke....

Answer (score 2):

It comes with the release of Angular 7 which is expected to release in one or two weeks from now. There has not been an official documentation yet.

Comment: `It comes with the release of Angular 7 `... It was just a joke from the article I've quoted above. If you search into the github repo you;ll see that there's no such things

Answer (score 0):

I found this fake points for angular 7 in this [post](https://www.code-sample.com/2018/04/what-new-in-angular-7-features.html?m=1)
"Important Notes About Angular 7 New Features :-

Most of the sites sharing below points but these are fake points. Someone made up fake release notes as a joke but developers/peoples started treating it like it was true.

A.       Splitting of @angular/core

B.      A new ng-compiler

C.      A new @angular/mine

D.      A new @aiStore"